# How do you make a list of numpy.float64?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using python. I made this numpy.float64 and this shows the Chicago Cubs' win times by decades.

```
yr1874to1880 = np.mean(wonArray[137:143])
yr1881to1890 = np.mean(wonArray[127:136])
yr1891to1900 = np.mean(wonArray[117:126])
yr1901to1910 = np.mean(wonArray[107:116])
yr1911to1920 = np.mean(wonArray[97:106])
yr1921to1930 = np.mean(wonArray[87:96])
yr1931to1940 = np.mean(wonArray[77:86])
yr1941to1950 = np.mean(wonArray[67:76])
yr1951to1960 = np.mean(wonArray[57:66])
yr1961to1970 = np.mean(wonArray[47:56])
yr1971to1980 = np.mean(wonArray[37:46])
yr1981to1990 = np.mean(wonArray[27:36])
yr1991to2000 = np.mean(wonArray[17:26])
yr2001to2010 = np.mean(wonArray[7:16])
yr2011to2016 = np.mean(wonArray[0:6])
```

I want to put them together but I don't know how to. I tried for the list but it did not work. Does anyone know how to put them together in order to put them in the graph? I want to make a scatter graph with matplotlib. Thank you.

Comment: Use a container? Why did the list not work?

Comment: I expect you can just iterate like this: for i in range(0,138): arr[i]=np.mean(wonArray[i:i+6])

Comment: ^What does arr mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with what you've shown, each variable you're setting becomes a float value. You can make them into a list by declaring:

`list_of_values = [yr1874to1880, yr1881to1890, ...]`

Adding all of the declared values to this results in a list of floats. For example, with just the two values above added:

```
>>>print list_of_values
[139.5, 131.0]
```

So that should explain how to obtain a list with the data from `np.mean()`. However, I'm guessing another question being asked is "how do I scatter plot this?" Using what is provided here, we have one axis of data, but to plot we need another (can't have a graph without x and y). Decide what the average wins is going to be compared against, and then that can be iterated over. For example, I'll use a simple integer in "decade" to act as the x axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

decade = 1
for i in list_of_values:
  y = i
  x = decade
  decade += 1
  plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: How do you make the decade start from the year 1874?

Comment: I changed decade equal to 1874 and decade += 10 but how do I make it to the range of 1874 to 2016?